# Using measures in multi-row cards

Tags: powerbi, powerbi-desktop

Right now, I have 3 individual cards on one of my screens that take 756 milliseconds in duration (according to the Performance Analyzer). From what I understand, the more visuals on screen, the more DAX queries are run that impact the performance.

So I started looking and trying the multi-row card. If I put each of the measures into the Fields for it and run the Performance Analyzer, it's a total of 229 ms. Which is great and exactly what I was looking for.

However, the UI behaviors are weird for it when using it this way. If I make the widget too wide, the rows become columns. If I make it too narrow, the title wraps. Is there a way around this? I've tried putting blank spaces into the values and such, but it didn't do anything.

I thought multi-row cards were intended to put several singular measurements into one visual that runs one DAX query. But it seems like it's more meant to summarize individual fields.